# How do I return the requested Angular GET format using an Express server?

Tags: javascript, angular, express, http, get

I'm writing both an Express server (localhost:3000), and an Angular app to "GET" values. The result in the Angular console always seems to be "JSON" event, even though the GET header specifies "text/html".

```
// Code in Angular
  async getTextHTML(){

    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'text/html')

    const result = await this.http.get('localhost:3000/order/total/30', {headers: httpHeaders}).toPromise()  

    console.info(result) // always prints the "JSON" result

  }

// Code in Express
app.get('/order/total/:orderID', async (req, resp) => {

    resp.status(200)
    resp.format({

        'text/html': function () {
            resp.send('text')  
        },
        
        'application/json': function () {
            resp.json({result:'json'})
        },
        
        default: function () {
            resp.type('text/html')
            resp.send('default')
        }
    })
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with some help of a friend.

```
const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'text/html')
```

should be

```
const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Accept', 'text/html')
```